# How to list instances for a type with applied type parameter in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I noticed that I don't know how to make GHCi print info about composite type.
Let's consider example

```
data X a = X (a Int)
type XList = X []

instance Show XList where show (X l) = "X (" ++ show l ++ ")"
```

I would like to see some how that "X []" implements Show.

Attempt 1

```
λ :i (X [])

<interactive>:1:2: error: parse error on input ‘X’
```

Attempt 2 - prints instances for list but not (X [])

```
λ :i X []
```

Attempt 3 - nothing about instances

```
λ :i XList
type XList = X []   -- Defined at <interactive>:20:1
```

Nonetheless Show instance is working when it is applicable

```
λ show (X [1,2,3])
"X ([1,2,3])"

λ show (X ['1'])

<interactive>:31:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Char’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:info` (what `:i` is short for) only works on names, not on expressions. To get the instances for an expression, use [`:instances`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances) instead:

```
λ :instances (X [])
instance [safe] Show XList -- Defined at <interactive>:6:10
instance [safe] Show XList -- Defined at <interactive>:6:10
```

Comment: since what GHC version instances command available? There is no such 8.8.3 and all dev activity years ago and mentions only a patch I need to apply.

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov It's new to GHC 8.10.1.